# Update proplist erlang

Tags: list, erlang, tuples

My first question is, can we update a proplist or a tuple of a proplist? If so, I have to replace a tuple value of a proplist:
Assume L,

```
 L = [{a, A}, {b, B}, {c, C}, {d, D}, {e, E} ...]
```

I want to replace a tuple `{b, B}` with a new Tuple `{b, New_B_Value}` and same with tuple `d` to get `{d, New_D_Value}`. So the output should be something like this:

```
 L = [{a, A}, {b, New_B_Value}, {c, C}, {d, D}, {d, New_D_Value} ...]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was looking for the same...:)

Comment: You can also just do `[{b, NewBValue} | L]` and ignore the duplication. Then a "garbage collection" is achieved by `lists:ukeysort/2`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use lists:keyreplace/4 function:

```
lists:keyreplace(b, 1, L, {b, New_B_Value}).
lists:keyreplace(d, 1, L, {d, New_D_Value}).
```

Answer (score 1):

If flexibility is not required, you can have some clauses to match the tuple of b and d and perform the substitution.

```
-module(t).

-export([test/0]).


test() ->
    L = [{a, valA}, {b, valB}, {c, valC}, {d, valD}, {e, valE}],
    test(L, [], new_b_value, new_d_value).

test([], A, _NewB, _NewD) -> A;
test([{b, _}|Rest], A, NewB, NewD) -> 
    test(Rest, A++[{b, NewB}], NewB, NewD);
test([{d, _}|Rest], A, NewB, NewD) -> 
    test(Rest, A++[{d, NewD}], NewB, NewD);
test([H|Rest], A, NewB, NewD) -> 
    test(Rest, A++[H], NewB, NewD).
```